# how to add multiple ec2 instances inside aws stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I want to create an AWS stack through portal or through cloud formation. But I want to add multiple EC2 instances in one single stack. I am not finding enough examples. How can I find one ?

Comment: you can create as many instances of a resource you want e.g. `AWS::EC2::Instance` as long as you use a different logical name and of coarse there is no conflict between the resources. As a tip, if you do not want to control the EC2 instances specifically then use a load ballancer with a launch configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add more `AWS::EC2::Instance` [resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) into your CloudFormation template.

For example:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Ec2 block device mapping",
  "Resources": {
    "MyEC2Instance1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId": "ami-79fd7eee",
        "KeyName": "testkey1",
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [
          {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sdm",
            "Ebs": {
              "VolumeType": "io1",
              "Iops": "200",
              "DeleteOnTermination": "false",
              "VolumeSize": "20"
            }
          },
          {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sdk",
            "NoDevice": {
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "MyEC2Instance2": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId": "ami-79fd7eee",
        "KeyName": "testkey2",
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [
          {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sdm",
            "Ebs": {
              "VolumeType": "io1",
              "Iops": "200",
              "DeleteOnTermination": "false",
              "VolumeSize": "20"
            }
          },
          {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sdk",
            "NoDevice": {
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```